# How to develop MS Outlook plug-in in VS 2010?

Tags: c#, winapi, outlook-addin

Can any one give me some good reference or tutorial links to develop plugin for outlook with visual studio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily create a VSTO(Visual Studio Tools for Office) add-in for Microsoft Outlook.

I'll use Office and Visual Studio 2010 as example:

In Visual Studio:

Select File -> New Project -> Office -> Outlook 2010 Add In

Replace ThisAddIn_Startup with the following:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Outlook starting up...");
    }
```

Running the application will launch Outlook displaying the message.

Now that you know how to create a new add in project have a look at these resources:

1) [Outlook developer video center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/gg263356)

2) [Outlook for developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/aa905455) - This MSDN page is dedicated to Microsoft Office Outlook developers and contains hundreds of examples, I believe you'll find the articles and examples on this site very helpful and like you've mentioned in your post if you get stuck somewhere you can always post a question here on SO.